# Determining whether $f(x) = \frac{\sin||x||}{e^{||x||}-1}$ for $x \neq 0$, $f(x) = 1$ for $x = 0$ is continuous at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

$f: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ is defined as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin||x||}{e^{||x||}-1} & \text{if $x \ne 0$} \\ 1 & \text{if $x = 0$.}\end{cases}$$

Note that $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^m$.

Is $f$ continuous at $0$?

Well, $\|0\| = 0$. How do I check the limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. By composition with the continuous map $x\longrightarrow \|x\|$, it suffices to prove it for 
$$g(t):=\frac{\sin t}{e^t-1}\qquad\forall t\neq 0\qquad g(0):=1$$ on $\mathbb{R}$. You can use l'Hospital, for instance, to see that $\displaystyle\lim_{t \to 0} g(t)=1=g(0)$, i.e. $g$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: ignore my last comment, thanks best answer

Comment: Congrats - you are now one of the elite trusted users.  Disneyworld?

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=\|x\|$. We have 
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin{t}}{t}=1
\mbox{ and }
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{e^{t}-1}{t}=1,
$$
hence $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

In fact the function $$g(z) = {\sin(z)\over e^z -1}$$ is an entire (and therefore infinitely differentiable) function for $z\in\mathbb{C}$.  So your function is infinitely differentiable except possibly at 0, because of the behavior of the norm function.

Comment: The OP did not specify the norm. So there is nor reason to assume it is differentiable anywhere. But that's a good idea to go analytic, +1.

Comment: What is the use of $\|\cdot\|$ in that event?

Comment: Are you saying that the $\ell^\infty$ norm, or the $\ell^1$ norm are useless?

Comment: The Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Do you only consider square integrable functions and throw away the integrable functions and the essentially bounded ones, in the same spirit? I don't follow you...

Comment: you have a composition of two functions. The function $b: x\mapsto \|x\|$ is infinitely differentiable except at $0$.   You have the function $b: x\mapsto sin(z)/(e^x -1)$  The function shown is $a\circ b$.  Since $b$ is infinitely differentiable except at zero and $a$ is infinitely differentiable everywhere, $a\circ b$ is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: If this was addressed to me, I wonder if you read my comments. A general norm is not "differentiable everywhere but at $0$". For instance, the $\ell^1$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not differentiable at $(\pm 1,0)$ and $(0,\pm 1)$, the $\ell^\infty$ norm is not differentiable at $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$. I know that the composition of differentiable functions is differentiable...

Comment: Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is.

Comment: It has never been assumed by the OP in the question, if you read it carefully. Where does it say that we consider the Euclidean norm? I just wanted to make sure the OP does not go with the idea that every norm is "differentiable everywhere but at $0$". And now I think it's time for me to give up...Regards.